# Python to Php Post data Using http request

Tags: python

```
import requests
req = requests.post('http://example.in/phppage.php', data = {'device_id':220,'tank_type':1,'level_pct':78,'water_flow':0,'water_over_flow':0})
print("HTTP Connection Status::"+str(req.status_code))
```

When I run this code it shows **http connection status 404**. What is wrong?

Comment: are you sure this url exist? ´http://example.in/phppage.php´

Comment: 404 means that the URL was not accessible. What happens if you go to the URL with your web browser? If that works, are you trying to access a website that is designed to send 404 to scripts like Python?

Comment: How is this a php question ? (tag removed)

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.5

Answer (score 0):

```
# importing the requests library
import requests

# defining the api-endpoint 
API_ENDPOINT = "http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php"

# your API key here
API_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

# your source code here
source_code = '''
print("Hello, world!")
a = 1
b = 2
print(a + b)
'''

# data to be sent to api
data = {'api_dev_key':API_KEY,
        'api_option':'paste',
        'api_paste_code':source_code,
        'api_paste_format':'python'}

# sending post request and saving response as response object
r = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, data = data)

# extracting response text `enter code here`
pastebin_url = r.text
print("The pastebin URL is:%s"%pastebin_url)
```